# Class in a struct

Tags: c++, class, structure

I have two questions.

1. I know it is possible to declare class objects in structs. But is it ethical to do that from design point of view?
2. In my scenario I have a structure with a huge number of member elements and I want to include a class object too. Here I have another question. If I memset() the whole struct the class handle is also reset. So, I check the size of the rest of the struct without the class object and subtract it while I call memset(), to get rid of this problem. (Please note that I am using STL class 'queue' here. And I cannot use sizeof() operator on the object, since it is not overloaded.)

But is this totally an unacceptable way to do that? Can you suggest some solution to this problem?

Comment: Ethics doesn't play into coding style.  Unless you're programming a machine that tortures babies.  And even then, it's only unethical to use the [Allman brace style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style).

Comment: @Nate Actually, they do, OP explicitly said “from a design point of view”. The C++ FAQ makes common references to “ethical” coding arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `struct` = `class` (except for default visibility).
- If you have a “huge number of members” you are probably doing something wrong, change your design, otherwise it becomes intractable.
- It is absolutely fine to nest classes and / or structs, where it makes sense. For instance, it’s common to define nested classes for implementation details (so a `linked_list` class could have a `node` member class).
- There’s no such thing as a “class object”, and it’s not clear what you mean by that.
- Don’t use `memset` – you probably don’t need it, just use normal constructors and assignment.
- > And I cannot use sizeof() operator on the object

  Wrong, you can use it.

Comment: +1 - _Don't use memset_.  This is much more important than the differences between `struct` and `class`.

Comment: #1 and default (unquslified) inheritence.

Comment: @John I subsumed that under visibility (it *is* the visibility of base class members to the derived class) since I felt making it explicit detracted from the important point.

Comment: @D.Shawley,@Konrad Can you give some reason why memset should not be used in case of structure initialisation? Is the use of structure constructor a normal practice?

Comment: @user1482353 What are you using `memset` for anyway? In the best case, it’s just a convoluted replacement for the constructor. In the worst case, its result is undefined and will introduce a bug in your code, since `memset` can only be used on plain old data. If you are using normal classes as member variables, or are using virtual functions, or some other stuff, there’s a high chance that `memset` will crash your code or do other bad things.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to avoid memset with classes and structures, and use constructors. In C++11 you can use initialization lists too under various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no much functional difference between classes and structs in c++. Structs exisist in c++ only for backward compatibility with C. So it is ok to have a class objects in structs. However I generally prefer structs that have only member variables with getter and setter. I dont use any functions inside struct that manupulate the data. If i need that then i will use class.